# Центрирование модального окна при загрузке

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Как мне сделать, чтобы модальное окно при загрузке всегда появлялось по центру страницы пользователя? Но чтобы оно не было фиксированным, т.к. его высота больше высоты экрана. 
Спасибо

Comment: `.mywnd { width: 60%; margin: auto; display:block; }`

Comment: Телепатией не страдаем, приведите пример кода

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url("https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/clouds_sun_sunset_colors_height_air_sky_48024_1920x1080.jpg");
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.modal .modal_content {
  width: 80%;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 75vh;
  max-height: 80vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal_content">Content.... <br><a href="http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwjvNb" target="_blank">Пример на codepen.io</a></div>
</div>
```

Про FlexBox: на [русском](http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/) и [английском](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Поддержка FlexBox [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)